# Discord.js Do something after a certain amount of time even when application restarts

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, settimeout

I'm trying to run a Discord Bot, which mutes a member, and unmutes after a certain amount of time.

My problem is, is that when i use `setTimeout()`, after a restart, it doesn't unmute after the appropriate time. How would I handle this to unmute after the time, even if the bot has restarted without getting interrupted by any Discord Rate Limits or Mongoose Rate Limits....

Comment: If you want to persist your timers across restarts, you'll need to save the information somewhere. E.g. in a file or a database.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, like cbr said, you'll need an external source to do the counting for you. Since the bot cannot run anything while it's offline, this is most likely the only solution. You could use a repl.it project as an API source.